# Rxjava, retrofit and multiple calls

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I've recently started using Rxjava and retrofit, and looking for any ideas on how to perform n number of retrofit post calls and track them via rxjava.  Once all actions have been completed a UI event will then occur.

I found this article: http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/ however it uses a for loop for initiating multiple request observables.  Maybe there is a more elegant way besides a for loop?  What is the best rxjava operator for this kind of effort?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop, you can create an Observable sequence from the List/Array then use flatMap/concatMap operator.

Using for loop:

```
GithubService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(GithubService.class, GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);  
for(String login : Data.githubList) {  
    service.getUser(login)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Github>() {
            @Override
            public final void onCompleted() {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e("GithubDemo", e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public final void onNext(Github response) {
                mCardAdapter.addData(response);
            }
        });

}
```

Pure Rx:

```
GithubService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(GithubService.class, GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
Observable.from(Data.githubList)
.flatMap(login -> service.getUser(login))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJava provides [a lot operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables) to combine multiple observables.

In your situation, you can use operator `merge`, and do UI work at `onComplete()`

Answer (score 0):

When multiple call depend on the same thing you can use flat map or concat map to utilize your call. Then finally update your view.

Comment: do you have any example for multiple network calls using concat

Answer (score 0):

**Use the [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator.**

For  Example :

you have 3 Retrofit Api and they are all return a string , and what you need is a long string merge by the 3 string.

So you need wait for the 3 api call are all return . and merge the return string with [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator.

Code will be like:

```
Observable.zip(
                api1,
                api2,
                api3,
                (resp1, resp2, resp3) -> resp1 + resp2 + resp3
        )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(resp -> {
                    // do something
                });
```